# Is GSM developed anymore?

Tags: mobile, lte, gsm, 4g

Is the GSM standard/spesification developed anymore? Does the GSM spesification/paper get any updates anymore?

Are UMTS, LTE, 5G NR versions of the GSM standard or separate standards? Of course them share a lot with GSM and are developed based on GSM, but to be pedantic how is this?

So, is there:

a)
The GSM spesification paper(s) v[1,2,3]
The UMTS spesification paper(s) v[1,2,3]
The LTE spesification paper(s) v[1,2,3]
The 5G NR spesification paper(s) v[1,2,3]

or

b)
The GSM spesification paper(s) and currently version of it is "5G NR". GSM "5G NR" v[1,2,3] like there is USB v4.

If a), has the GSM spesification paper got any updates anymore?

---

I ask because articles about LTE or 5G NR many times call them GSM and difference is unclear. Some guys also says GSM is not there anymore, but some says all is GSM... and so on.